# Why does #my_id override .my_class:hover in CSS?

Tags: css, hover

CSS rules applied to IDs have higher priority than class rules, that makes sense. What I don't get is why this:

```
<div id="global_button" class="global_button_class"></div>

#global_button
{
   opacity:0.7;
}

.global_button_class:hover
{
   opacity:1;
}
```

...doesn't change the opacity when the mouse is hovered over the button, but if I change from:

```
.global_button_class:hover
```

...to:

```
#global_button:hover
```

...it works. I mean, if the hover state isn't defined by the id, why doesn't `.global_button_class:hover` kick in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically because you have set the opacity property using the elements ID it is setting the state for hover, focus, active etc on that too.

When you try to set the hover state using the class name you have attached it gets overwridden by the previously stated ID which gets more weight than the class.

ID > CLASS

Comment: If I have multiple elements with class="global_button_class" and I do .global_button_class:hover{display:none} will all the elements with that class be removed when at least one has the mouse hover it? or just the one with the mouse hover it?

Comment: Only the one you hover over will be affected.

Comment: Although this answer doesn't refer to other web sites as the other ones...it's the most complete on site. I knew that ID had priority to Class but I didn't remember that it was also setting the rules to the other states (focus,hover,active,etc) and the class:hover would try to overwrite them

Answer (score 1):

**Hi now used to this**

```
#global_button.global_button_class:hover{
opacity:1;
}
```

***[LIve demo](http://tinkerbin.com/HxCzTPsx)***

because you `define opacity into` id or `id` value is **more than high** `class`

```
ID value is  == 100
Class value is == 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all down to specificity (explained much better [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)). Basically the order of precedence is id class element.

Malarkey gives a nice slant on it George Lucas stylee ( [css precedence explained](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html))

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the solution just be:

```
<div id="global_button"></div>

#global_button {
opacity:0.7;
}

#global_button:hover {
opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: I've mentioned that on the question itself...and that I knew ID precedes Class...but I thought class:selector preceded id...but because it's overriding css attributes of a higher priority selector it wont work